# Python 2: function alias or macro

Tags: python, macros

I am wondering if there is a way to create macros or aliases for functions in Python 2.7.

Example: I am trying to use the `logging` module and create aliases/macros for functions `logging.debug`, `logging.info`, `logging.error`, etc. If I use those functions as they are in the place where I want the log, everything works fine. But if I try to create an 'alias' function wrapper like this:

```
def debugLog(message):
    logging.debug(message)
```

... then the line number reporting no longer works as intended, the line reported always states the location of the wrapper and not the actual log, which isn't any real use.

I did find this solution:

```
import logging
from logging import info as infoLog
from logging import debug as debugLog
from logging import error as errorLog
....
```

... but it is not suitable for me since I also create my own logging severity:

```
logging.addLevelName(60, "NORMAL")
```

... and I'd like to create an alias/macro like `normalLog(message)=logging.log(60, message)` for it as well if it's possible? I couldn't find anything comprehensive in [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) or online.

Comment: Isn't that a function?
def normalLog(message):
    logging.log(60, message)

Comment: What if you just write `normalLog = lambda m: logging.log(60, m)`?

Comment: @OferSadan:  That would exhibit the same issue.

Comment: For recommended patterns I suggest looking at [Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools
import logging
normalLog = functools.partial(logging.log, 60)
```

It works pretty well:

```
normalLog("Hey!!")
Level 60:root:Hey!!
```

`partial` binds arguments to function calls and return a partial object (a callable object that holds the necesary information), so you can also use it in the `addLevelName` method:

```
activateLevel = functools.partial(logging.addLevelName, 60, "NORMAL")
activateLevel()
```

Here you have a [live working example](https://repl.it/JnVj/1), notice that the log line is properly reported.

Comment: @mgilson check the live example, it work as it should.

Comment: Ahh ... but try to run it in `pypy`.  If you do, you're in for a bit of a surprise.  IOW, you're relying on implementation details of `functools.partial`.

Comment: This happens to work on CPython because C functions don't get Python-level stack entries on CPython.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a frame object to get the line number.  You can get a frame object in a number of ways, in the example below I use `sys._getframe()`, the parameter 1 gives the previous stack frame.  `sys._getframe()` is not guaranteed to be present on all Python non-C implementations.  Several other functions return frame objects, including the `inspect` module.

```
import sys

def debugLog(message):
    line = sys._getframe(1).f_lineno
    print line, ':', message


x = 42
print x
debugLog("A")
y = x + 1
print y
debugLog("B")
```

Gives:

```
42
10 : A
43
13 : B
```

Comment: `inspect.currentframe` might be slightly better than `sys._getframe`